# Creating decision rules on pixel level in time series layer in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, landsat, time-series

I am using Landsat 5, 7, 8 images and RStudio. My goal is to compute the disturbance in a given area using the Vegetation Change Tracker (VCT) algorithm. I would like to ask you if you could provide me a general guidance on how to construct it using R Studio. I computed the IFZ of each individual image, I created the LTSS, I have the NDVI and the NBR of each year. My problem is on how to create the rules required form the VCT (see the image below).[image: Decision rules used by eh vct algorithm (Huang, 2010)]

The acronyms CLIV, MNCLIV and MNCHIV means:

- the pixel was classified as a forest at least in 2 sequentially images,
- the minimum years of sequentially images needed for a pixel to be classified as a forest (2 years) and
- minimum number of consecutive high IFZ values for a pixel to be classified as a non-forest pixel.

The paper named An automated approach for reconstructing recent forest disturbance history using dense Landsat time series stack.

Comment: What is the form of your data? How are the various bands and time-point rasters stored?

Comment: I had yearly Landsat images of every band in raster format (.tif) which I downloaded using Google Earth Engine. Also, I had the NDVI and NBR indices in the same format for every year. Based on those indices I created random points in areas which I knew that it was dense forest (NDVI > 0.6) or a disturbance was occurred (e.g. a fire). Then, I used the Point Sampling Tool in QGIS in order to check the spectral value in the bands B3, B5 & B7 and finally I computed the FZ and IFZ indices for every image. Lastly, I created a time series stack of the yearly IFZ indices in R using the rts package.

Comment: Edit your question and describe the form of the R objects you have - their names, their layers, their time structure, a description of what the values are and so on. Give the output of `summary` or `print` on the objects. At the moment we can't get past the first step since we have no idea where your water classification is.